# Issue interacting with some child widgets in Flutter's InteractiveViewer

Tags: flutter

I have a Stack as a child of an InteractiveViewer without constraints. I am using it to show a mindmap of widgets that are essentially Text widgets and TextFields. Some child widgets will receive taps but not others. It seems that they are not working beyond a certain limit.

I have tried to set constrained = false, tried increasing the SizedBox the stack was contained in.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that widgets with negative x or y coordinates were visible but would not receive gestures within an InteractiveViewer.

Shifting the position of all the child widgets to positive territory fixed the problem.